# Трансформация в нестандартную проекцию django+postgis

Tags: django, transform, postgis, spatial

На сервере в базе `test` имеется таблица `table` с пространственными данными (postgis-based). Данные хранятся в стандартной проекции WGS-84 (srid 4326). Теперь мне нужно их обработать и перевести в другую проекцию. Таблица с проекциями называется spatial_ref_sys, она стандартная для postgis, но в неё добавлены дополнительные проекции - для них назначен srid и определены параметры.
В таблице table хранится очень много записей, а перевести в другую проекцию нужно только некоторые. Когда они отфильтрованы, я могу обратиться к конкретной геометрии и трансформировать координаты командой transform:

```
geom = obj.geom.transform(self.options['srid'])
```

Это работает, только если `srid` стандартный, потому что, оказывается, `transform` обращается не к таблице `spatial_ref_sys`, а к каким-то файлам GDAL. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно обратиться именно к проекциям, которые хранятся в spatial_ref_sys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как указано в [источнике](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry/#GEOSGeometry.transform), параметр `ct` метода `transform` может быть не только `srid`, но и напрямую параметром `proj4text`, который описан как раз в таблице `spatial_ref_sys`. Получить proj4text можно, обратившись напрямую к модели SpatialRefSys:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.models import PostGISSpatialRefSys
proj4 = PostGISSpatialRefSys.objects.get(srid=self.options['srid']).proj4text
geom = obj.geom.transform(proj4)
```

Answer (score 0):

не `к каким-то файлам GDAL` а вполне к конкретным

находите папку `locate gdal_data`

берете, например, `esri_epsg.wkt`

```
sudo nano esri_epsg.wkt
```

в конец добавляете свою проекцию в формате 32767,PROJCS["..."] (ну как в файле)

также добавьте проекцию в `spatial_ref_sys`

профит.